# multiple orderer organizations

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have two organizations for ordering (type= Raft). one of them has two orderers and the second one has three orderers, in configtx.yaml there are `Ordererorg1MSP` and `Ordererorg2MSP` MSPs.
my configtx.taml:

```
Organizations:
    - &Ordererorg1
        Name: Ordererorg1MSP
        ID: Ordererorg1MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.orderer.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Ordererorg1MSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Ordererorg1MSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Ordererorg1MSP.admin')"
    - &Orgorg1
        Name: Orgorg1MSP
        ID: Orgorg1MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orgorg1MSP.admin', 'Orgorg1MSP.peer', 'Orgorg1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orgorg1MSP.admin', 'Orgorg1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orgorg1MSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer1.org1.example.com
              Port: 2050
    - &Ordererorg2
        Name: Ordererorg2MSP
        ID: Ordererorg2MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org2.orderer.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Ordererorg2MSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Ordererorg2MSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Ordererorg2MSP.admin')"
    - &Orgorg2
        Name: Orgorg2MSP
        ID: Orgorg2MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orgorg2MSP.admin', 'Orgorg2MSP.peer', 'Orgorg2MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orgorg2MSP.admin', 'Orgorg2MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orgorg2MSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer1.org2.example.com
              Port: 2050
Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_4_3: true
        V1_3: false
        V1_1: false
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V1_4_2: true
        V1_1: false
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V1_4_2: true
        V1_3: false
        V1_2: false
        V1_1: false
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    Addresses:
                - peer1.org1.orderer.example.com:7050
                - peer1.org2.orderer.example.com:7050
    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
                    - Host: peer1.org1.orderer.example.com
                      Port: 7050
                      ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.orderer.example.com/orderers/peer1.org1.orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
                      ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.orderer.example.com/orderers/peer1.org1.orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
                    - Host: peer1.org2.orderer.example.com
                      Port: 7050
                      ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org2.orderer.example.com/orderers/peer1.org2.orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
                      ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org2.orderer.example.com/orderers/peer1.org2.orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:
    Channel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                    - *Orgorg1
                    - *Orgorg2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

    OrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults

            Organizations:
                - *Ordererorg1
                - *Ordererorg2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *Ordererorg1
                - <<: *Ordererorg2
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Orgorg1
                    - *Orgorg2
```

when I want to create channel, I face error and the DEBUG logs says:

```
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 7b9 0xc0007edbe0 gate 1588594370452563334 evaluation starts
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 7ba 0xc0007edbe0 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 7bb 0xc0007edbe0 principal evaluation fails
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 7bc 0xc0007edbe0 gate 1588594370452563334 evaluation fails
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 7bd Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/Ordererorg2MSP/Readers
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 7be == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Ordererorg2MSP/Readers
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 7bf == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Ordererorg1MSP/Readers ==
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 7c0 Principal deserialization failure (MSP OrdererMSP is unknown) for identity 0
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 7c1 0xc0007fe250 gate 1588594370452661614 evaluation starts
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 7c2 0xc0007fe250 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 7c3 0xc0007fe250 principal evaluation fails
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 7c4 0xc0007fe250 gate 1588594370452661614 evaluation fails
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 7c5 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/Ordererorg1MSP/Readers
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 7c6 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Ordererorg1MSP/Readers
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 7c7 Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ Ordererorg1MSP/Readers Ordererorg2MSP/Readers ]
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 7c8 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/Readers
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 7c9 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Readers
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 7ca Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ Application/Readers Consortiums/Readers Orderer/Readers ]
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 7cb Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Readers
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 7cc == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Readers
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [orderer.common.msgprocessor] Apply -> DEBU 7cd SigFilter evaluation failed: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Readers' sub-policies to be satisfied, policyName: /Channel/Readers, ConsensusState: STATE_NORMAL
2020-05-04 12:12:50.452 UTC [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 7ce [channel: greenwebgenesis] Client authorization revoked for deliver request from 10.0.1.36:33346: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Readers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied
```

I guess in each fabric network, we can only have one ordering organization under the MSP of `OrdererMSP`. is it correct?

can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Hey will u please send us configtx.yaml ? for sure you have done some mistakes in the configtx

Comment: thank you Narendranath Reddy. I updated the question and added the configtx.yaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the logs you are getting `Principal deserialization failure (MSP OrdererMSP is unknown)` but in `configtx.yaml` file, you aren't using `OrdererMSP` hence check the value of `ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID` in docker file.

Answer (score 1):

Mistake: you have removed orderer orgs from consortium

```
Consortiums:
    SampleConsortium:
        Organizations:
            - *Orgorg1
            - *Orgorg2
```

Mistake correction:

```
    Consortiums:
        SampleConsortium:
            Organizations:
                - *Orgorg1
                - *Orgorg2
                - *Ordererorg1
                - *Ordererorg2
```

I have corrected policies also if you expectily mention peer and client then the issued certificate type also should be peer and clint so make it member and you are good to go.

Please find the corrected configtx.yaml

```
Organizations:
    - &Ordererorg1
        Name: Ordererorg1MSP
        ID: Ordererorg1MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.orderer.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Ordererorg1MSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Ordererorg1MSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Ordererorg1MSP.admin')"
    - &Orgorg1
        Name: Orgorg1MSP
        ID: Orgorg1MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orgorg1MSP.member'"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orgorg1MSP.member'"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orgorg1MSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer1.org1.example.com
              Port: 2050
    - &Ordererorg2
        Name: Ordererorg2MSP
        ID: Ordererorg2MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org2.orderer.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Ordererorg2MSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Ordererorg2MSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Ordererorg2MSP.admin')"
    - &Orgorg2
        Name: Orgorg2MSP
        ID: Orgorg2MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orgorg2MSP.member'"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orgorg2MSP.member'"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Orgorg2MSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer1.org2.example.com
              Port: 2050
Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_4_3: true
        V1_3: false
        V1_1: false
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V1_4_2: true
        V1_1: false
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V1_4_2: true
        V1_3: false
        V1_2: false
        V1_1: false
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    Addresses:
                - peer1.org1.orderer.example.com:7050
                - peer1.org2.orderer.example.com:7050
    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
                    - Host: peer1.org1.orderer.example.com
                      Port: 7050
                      ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.orderer.example.com/orderers/peer1.org1.orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
                      ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.orderer.example.com/orderers/peer1.org1.orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
                    - Host: peer1.org2.orderer.example.com
                      Port: 7050
                      ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org2.orderer.example.com/orderers/peer1.org2.orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
                      ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org2.orderer.example.com/orderers/peer1.org2.orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:
    Channel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                    - *Orgorg1
                    - *Orgorg2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

    OrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Ordererorg1
                - *Ordererorg2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *Ordererorg1
                - <<: *Ordererorg2
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Orgorg1
                    - *Orgorg2
                    - *Ordererorg1
                    - *Ordererorg2
```

I have written book: If you know more about mastering in Hyperledger fabric you can get from here:
- https://leanpub.com/masteringhyperledgerfabric
- https://amzn.to/2Yyl1aS

Comment: thanks for your answer. I added orderer orgs to the consortium and changed the policies to `.member`. but still have the same error! are you sure we can have multiple organizations for ordering?

Comment: yes there is no issue on that we can have multiple orderers otherwise there is no need of hyperledger fabric if one organization take central authority of orderering

Comment: @PouyaShojaei In the logs you are getting `Principal deserialization failure (MSP OrdererMSP is unknown)` but in configtx.yaml file, you aren't using `OrdererMSP` hence check the value of `ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID` in docker file.

Comment: Kindly send us all files that you are using and will figure out where the problem is mainly Orderer compose files